# Lookup columns not visible in designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, lookup-column

I have a massive 2013 list workflow build to handle projects on the SP Online platform. This workflow utilises a few lookup columns and people fields - but no more than 5!

For some strange reason I simply cannot see on of the lookup fields I have created recently. It simple isn't in the "Current item" list of fields.

Any idea what has gone wrong, and even better how to fix it?

Edited: I testet just for the fun of it if a new lookup column would show up. It seems lookup to other lists works perfectly fine, but lookup to the same list is not present. Is that really by design?

It's NOT an option to rebuild the workflow from scratch, neither is it an option to create a new lookup and delete the old one!

Comment: Is this a list workflow or a content-type workflow? 2010 or 2013? Nintex?

Comment: It's a normal 2013 list workflow, no 3rd party stuff going on.

Comment: For now I'v used the REST api to fetch the lookup element, but it really feels like crossing to river to get water...

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your designer and wait for a while, then check if you can find the new created lookup column.

[image]

Besides, try clearing SharePoint Designer cache and re-open it, see if it works.

1. Close SharePoint Designer 2013;
2. Delete all the files from location: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache;
3. Delete all the files from location: %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache.

How to clear SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 cache:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx

Comment: The field was added a few days ago. Shouldn't have to wait that long :)

Comment: Have your refreshed the designer after creating the field in the list?

Comment: Yes my computer isn't running for several days without a reboot. I have closed and opned the designer several times since the field was added. Out of curiosity are you able to access a lookup field on a list which looks op upon the list itself?

Comment: Per my testing, the new created lookup column will display in the workflow after refreshing the designer. Can you try to clear the designer cache? Check if the issue occurs because the cache.

Comment: Other lookup works as well - have you tried with a lookup that targets the list itself?

Comment: OK, I have reproduced your issue. It only happens on the lookup column that targets to the list itself.

Comment: Yup it would seem Microsoft for some unknown reason thinks that isn't allowed.

Comment: You can contact Office 365 technical support from Support > New Service request. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/contact-support-for-business-products-admin-help-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b#ID0EAADAAA=online Provide as much additional information as possible to describe your issue.

Comment: Yeah well I havn't had much luck so to be honest, I can't be bothered with it...